Continuous functions on compact Hausdorff space with a special property.
Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $- : X \to X$ be a homeomorphism of $X$ with period 2. i.e, $\bar{(\bar{t})} = t, \forall t \in X$.
Define $C(X,-) := \{ f \in C(X,\mathbb{C}): f(\bar{t})=\overline{f(t)}, \forall t \in X \}$.
Fix $t \in X$, prove that $t=\bar{t} \Leftrightarrow f(t) \in \mathbb{R},  \forall f \in C(X,-)$.
One direction is obvious.
Thanks in advance.

If $t\neq\bar{t}$, then there is a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $f(t)=i$ and $f(\bar{t})=0$. Define $g(u)=f(\bar{u})+\overline{f(u)}$. Then $g(\bar{u})=\overline{g(u)}$ and $g(t)=-i$.
